# Find the longest occurrence of the "aeiou" in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, algorithm

I was recently doing an interview and was asked multiple questions, one of the questions was this and I had a bit of trouble trying to answer it.

Given a string, find the longest occurrence of vowels "aeiou" that appear. 
The substring of vowels do not have to be consecutive, and there can be repeats.

The goal is the find the max occurrence of each vowel and join them, but it must be in the order of "a","e","i","o","u".

Edit: In addition, each individual vowel character must be chained as well. In the example below, there is "aaa" and "aa" , since 3 is longer, our result must contain the longer chain.

For example: 
Input: "aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae"
Result: aaaeiiiou

The code that I have tried is below:

EDIT: Following the solution, I have written this below but I am still running into issues with strings such as "aeiouaaaeeeiiiooouuu". The correct result for that would be 15 but I am getting 5.

```js
var findLongestVowels = function(s){
var count = 1;
var i = 0; 
var j = 0;
var vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u'];
var total = 0; 
var array = [];
while (i < s.length){
    if (s.charAt(i) == vowels[j] && s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(i+1) ){
        count++;
    }
    else if (s.charAt(i) == vowels[j] && s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1)){
        if (j === 0 && !array[vowels[j]]){
            array[vowels[j]] = count;
        }
        else if (j === 0 && array[vowels[j]]){
            array[vowels[j]] = Math.max(array[vowels[j]],count);
        }
        else if (j !== 0 && !array[vowels[j]] && array[vowels[j-1]]){
            array[vowels[j]] = array[vowels[j-1]] + count;
        }
        else if (j !== 0 && array[vowels[j]] && array[vowels[j-1]]){
            array[vowels[j]] = Math.max(array[vowels[j]],array[vowels[j-1]] + count);
        }
      count = 1; 
    }
    else if (s.charAt(i) == vowels[j+1] && array[vowels[j]]){
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    i++;
  }
  console.log(array);
  console.log('Answer: ' + array[vowels[j]]);
}

findLongestVowels("eeeeebbbagtaagaaajaaaaattyuhiejjhgiiiouaae");
```

Am I at least going in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if the string is `aaeagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae`?

Comment: For example: Input: `"aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae"` result: `aaaeiiiou`.... why noy 5 `a`??

Comment: Sorry I wasn&amp;#39;t very clear in the post, that&amp;#39;s another condition too, it has to be the longest occurrence of each individual vowel character chained together, so if there are 3's and then 5 's before the e, then we must take the 5 and drop the 3.

Comment: [`console.log('aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae'.match(/[aeiou]+/gi).reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b));`](https://jsfiddle.net/sytzrafn/3/)

Comment: @Tushar Looks like OP wants to join the max occurrence of each vowel and join them, which explains the original output as well.

Comment: Yea, I don't have an issue with finding the longest occurrence, but it's the order I am stuck on.

Comment: Just count the number of occurrence of the vowels right? or am I missing smt? Do they need to be in any specific order?

Comment: Yes they also need to be in that specific order

Comment: It is still not clear, according to ur condition, the result for `aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae` should be `aaaaaeiiiou`, why drop two `a` in it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you know dynamic programming?

Comment: I haven't touched it since there was a class in college that taught it, but would that help in this case?

Comment: @Veve As the code is not working as expected, it cannot be migrated to CR.SE.

Comment: See my answer for more details

Comment: Posted answer using regex and array methods :)

Comment: Hmm, ur code seems overly complicated. You can take a look at my [Java code](https://ideone.com/aHvgYz)

Comment: Added JavaScript code.

Comment: @PhamTrung your code returns 12 for "eioeeeiiiooouuu" but there's no 'a' :)

Answer (score 4):

We can solve this in `O(n)` time. Consider that for each block, if its vowel is at index `v` in the list of vowels, we are only interested in the best solution for the block with a vowel at index `v-1` *in the order of vowels*. We save the last best solution for each block type (each vowel) as we go along:

```
   |aaa|g|t|aa|y|u|h|i|e|jj|h|g|iii|o|u|aa|e
b:  1       2    3   4 5        6   7 8 9  10

b 1: v[a] = 3
b 2: v[a] = max(2,3)
b 3: v[u] = None recorded for v-1
b 4: v[i] = None recorded for v-1
b 5: v[e] = 1 + 3
b 6: v[i] = 3 + 4
b 7: v[o] = 1 + 7
b 8: v[u] = 1 + 8 // answer 
b 9: v[a] = max(2,3)
b 10: v[e] = 1 + 3
```

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(str){
  console.log(`String: ${ str }\n`);
  
  var vowels = {
    a: {best: 0, prev: null},
    e: {best: 0, prev: 'a'},
    i: {best: 0, prev: 'e'},
    o: {best: 0, prev: 'i'},
    u: {best: 0, prev: 'o'}
  };
  
  function getBlock(i){
    let length = 1;
    
    while (str[i+1] && str[i] == str[i+1]){
      length++;
      i++;
    }
      
    return length;
  }
  
  for (let i=0; i<str.length;){
    let length = getBlock(i);
    
    console.log(`i: ${ i }; length: ${ length }`)
    
    if (!vowels[str[i]]){
      i = i + length;
      continue;
    }
    
    if (!vowels[str[i]].prev){
      vowels[str[i]].best = Math.max(
        vowels[str[i]].best,
        length
      );
      
    // make sure the previous vowel
    // exists in the string before
    // this vowel
    } else if (vowels[ vowels[str[i]].prev ].best){
      vowels[str[i]].best = Math.max(
        vowels[str[i]].best,
        length + vowels[ vowels[str[i]].prev ].best
      );
    }
    
    i = i + length;
  }
  
  console.log(`\n${ JSON.stringify(vowels) }\n\n`);
  
  return vowels['u'].best;
}

var s = 'eeeeebbbagtaagaaajaaaaattyuhiejjhgiiiouaae';
console.log(f(s) + '\n\n');

s = 'aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae';
console.log(f(s) + '\n\n');

s = 'aeiouaaaeeeiiiooouuu';
console.log(f(s));
```

Comment: Nice answer, much better than mine

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail about your algorithm or maybe provide some code? I just tried to implement it that way and I was successful for every case except for a case like this "aeiouaaaeeeiiiooouuu" in whch the result should be 15 but using that I am getting 5, am I missing something?

Comment: @PhamTrung I have just edited the question with the new code I have written following the solution

Comment: @LeoLi added code. (Please note that the console log in the snippet viewer is sometimes truncated. Run the code elsewhere to view the console log in full.)

Comment: Thank you @גלעדברקן !! This was very helpful and definitely helped me learn alot!

Comment: @LeoLi great, I'm happy to hear that!

Comment: @LeoLi If you think the question has been answered satisfactorily, feel free to accept the appropriate answer (click on the checkmark near the votes on the answer) so other people will know it's been resolved :)

Comment: Viewing his history, I don't think he is ever accepted an answer.

Comment: @PhamTrung ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by using dynamic programming technique.

First, we have string `x` and we want to find the longest string for this string.

Traversing the string `x` from start to end, assuming at index `i`, we are trying to find vowel `e`, there are two possibilities:

- Current character is `e`, so we take the whole block and move to next character
- Or, we can try with the next character

So, we have our pseudocode:

```
int[][]dp;
int largestBlock (int index, int currentVowel, String x, String vowels){
    if (currentVowel == 5) {
       // We found all 5 vowel
       return 0;
    }
    if visited this state (index, currentVowel) before {
       return dp[index][currentVowel]; 
    }
    int result = largestBlock(index + 1, currentVowel, x, vowels) ;
    if (x[index] == vowels[currentVowel]){
        int nxt = nextIndexThatIsNotVowel(index, currentVowel, x, vowels);
        result =  max(result, nxt - index + largestBlock(nxt, currentVowel + 1, x , vowels));        
    }
    return dp[index][currentVowel] = result;
}
```

Time complexity is O(n * m) with m is number of vowels which is 5 in this case.

Comment: posted O(n) solution :) (also +1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember biggest combination of individual vowels.

Use `reduce`, `map` and `Object.values`

```js
var vowels = "aeiou";
var input = "aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae";

var output = Object.values( 
  input.split( "" ).reduce( ( a, c, i, arr ) => {
     var lastChar = arr[ i - 1 ];
     if ( !vowels.includes( c ) ) return a; //if not vowel, return accumulator
     if ( c != lastChar ) //if not same as last character then create a new array
     {
         a[ c ] = a[ c ] || [];
         a[ c ].push( [ c ] );
     }
     else //else push to the last array;
     {
         var lastCombo = a[ c ].slice( -1 )[ 0 ];
         lastCombo.push(c)       
     }
     return a; //return accumulator
  } , {}) ).map( s => {
     var char = s[0][0]; //find the character to repeat
     var maxLength = Math.max.apply( null, s.map( s => s.length ) ); //find how many times to repeat
     return Array( maxLength + 1 ).join( char ); 
  }).join( "" ); //join all the vowels
  
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just one of many possible solutions - feel free to try it out.

1. Store every vowel you're interested in, in `vowels` array.
2. Use `map` to loop over every vowel in array, create regex from vowel to split string into array of vowels. For example "aaabdmedaskaa" would be split into `["aaa", "a", "aa"]`.
3. Filter this array so it doesn't include empty strings.
4. Sort it by length, so accesing `0` element would give you longest occurance
5. After mapping over every vowel, return the result - filter out "undefined" in case some of your vowels don't occur at all and regex results in empty array (accesing empty array's 0th element would result in `undefined`), join array of occurances into a result string.

The regex created from "a" will be `[^a]+` which means *any character sequence that does not include "a"*.

```js
function findLongestOccurance(str) {
  const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  const result = vowels.map(vowel => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`[^${vowel}]+`);
    return str.split(regex)
       .filter(r => r !== "")
       .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
  });
  return result.filter(occ => typeof(occ) !== "undefined").join("");
}

console.log(findLongestOccurance("aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae"));
```

Comment: Your code returns the answer for "aaagtaayuhiejjhgooooiiiouaae" with both "iii" and "oooo" in the solution. Unless I misunderstood the question, shouldn't the chosen blocks be in order of appearance in the string?

Comment: Following the logic from example in the question: "For example: Input: "aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae" Result: aaaeiiiou" - this is the desired output. Passing "aaagtaayuhiejjhgooooiiiouaae" should result in "aaaeiiioooou" unless I misunderstood the question

Comment: That would seem like a pretty trivial question :) Just join the biggest block of each vowel found anywhere in the string?

Comment: It's just how i understood it - only OP can answer i guess

Answer (score 0):

Why not regex?

```js
var result = /(a+).*(e+).*(i+).*(o+).*(u+)/.exec("aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae");
console.log(result[1]+result[2]+result[3]+result[4]+result[5]);
```

Comment: This is not working as expected. The desired output is `aaaeiiiou`. Note the three `i`s. Will not work for strings like `aeiouaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiioooooouuuuuuuuuu`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from what I understand from the question the result for Input: "aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae" should be aaaaaeiiiou, like @PhamTrung asked in the comments but didn't get answered.

Because it a job interview I would start with the first thing that comes to mind, namely brute force the solution out of this

```js
function a(string, prefix='') {
    if(!string.length){
        return prefix
    }
    if(!/[aeiou]/.test(string[0])){
        return a(string.substr(1), prefix)
    }
    const option1 = a(string.substr(1), prefix)
    const option2 = a(string.substr(1), prefix+string[0])
    const validateRegex = /^a+e+i+o+u+$/
    
    const isValidOption1 = validateRegex.test(option1)
    const isValidOption2 = validateRegex.test(option2)
    if(isValidOption1 && isValidOption2){
        if(option1.length > option2.length) {
            return option1
        }
        return option2
    }
    if(isValidOption1) {
        return option1
    }
    if(isValidOption2) {
        return option2
    }
    return null
}
const input = 'aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae'
console.log(a(input))
```

This has a terrible run time though, we are trying all possible substring that contains only vowels, than we are discarding those that aren't of the form required (a+e+i+o+u+) and than choosing only the biggest of them all. If I'm not mistake this has a worst case of ∑(n choose i) which is O(n^n) - *well, the actual worst case here would be a stackOverflow exception for sufficiently large n in which case we'd have to reimplement this with a loop instead of recursing. In this case we could still get an out of memory exception in which case we'd be out of options but to improve our algorithm. It's fair to imagine that if the input were large enough that we got an out of memory exception than our code would also be slow enough to not be a reasonable solution to the problem. I'm just arguing all this because these are things that an interviewer would possibly like to see that you are aware of, meaning you know enough of CS 101.*

Following that the interviewer would ask if I can improve the performance. This is a solution with running time of O(n).

```js
const input = 'aeiouaaaeeeiiiooouuu'
let curr = { "1": {price: -1} }
const nodes = []
const voewels = '1aeiou'
const getPrevLetter = (node) => voewels[voewels.indexOf(node.letter) -1]
let resultNode
function setUpNodeByCurrent(node, letter){
    node.price = curr[letter].price + 1
    node.previous = curr[letter]
}
function setBestResultIfNeeded(node){
    if(node.letter !== 'u') {
        return
    }
    if(!resultNode || resultNode.price < node.price) {
        resultNode = node
        return
    }
}
function setCurrent(letter){
    const node = {
        letter,
        price: 0
    }
    const prevLetter = getPrevLetter(node)
    if(!prevLetter || !curr[prevLetter]){
        // either letter isn't on of aeiou or
        // we got to an i without ever seeing an e, an o without ever seeing an i, ... this letter is irrelevant 
        return
    }
    if(curr[node.letter]) {
        setUpNodeByCurrent(node, node.letter)
    } 
    if(node.price < curr[prevLetter].price + 1) {
        setUpNodeByCurrent(node, prevLetter) 
    }
    curr[node.letter] = node
    setBestResultIfNeeded(node)
}
function getStringResult(node){
    let result = ''
    while(node) {
        result = node.letter + result
        node = node.previous
    }
    return result
}
function getResult(){
    const node = resultNode //getBestResultNode()
    const result = getStringResult(node)  
    console.log(result)   
    console.log(result.length)
}
for(let l of input){
    setCurrent(l)
}
getResult()
```

This can be seen as a simplification of the [longest path problem over a DAG](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/171/Syllabus/11-Graph/Docs/longest-path-in-dag.pdf) basically you'd run through the string and every `a` points to the next occurance of `a` and the next occurance of `e`. `e` points to the next `e` and to the next `i` and so on. You'd than have a start node pointing to every occurance of a and an end node pointed to by every occurance of u. Now what you want is the longest path from the start node to the end node which is an O(|V|+|E|), now |V|<=n and |E|<=2n since every node in your graph has at most 2 vertices going out of it so the total running time is O(n). I have simplified the code to build the result as it goes on building the graph, basically I already calculate the cost on the go so when I finished building a graph similar to what I described I already know what the result is.

Note that this solution is based on the assumption that the input string is one that necessarily has a solution embedded in it. If the input string is unsolvable (there isn't and aeiou sequence in it) than this case would need to be properly handled, it is actually trivial to add the code that handles that. The first solution will return null in such a case(if I'm not mistaken)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a substring which contains the maximum number of vowels and you also want to give {specify} the length of the substring then you should use this program:

```
    let newk = s;
    const elementsArray = [];
    const tempoArray = [];
    const counting = [];
    const maxPoint = [];

    let count
    for (var i = 0; i < newk.length; i++) {
        while (tempoArray.length > 0) {
            tempoArray.pop();
        }
        let fk = i + k;
        if (fk <= newk.length) {
            for (let j = i; j < fk; j++) {
                tempoArray.push(newk[j]);
            }
            let makingArray = tempoArray.toString();
            elementsArray.push(makingArray);
        } else {
        //    console.log(" ");
        }
    }


    for (let q = 0; q < elementsArray.length; q++) {
            count = 0
            let tempString = new String(elementsArray[q]).split(",")

            for (let l = 0; l < tempString.length; l++) {
                if (tempString[l] == "a" || tempString[l] == "e" || tempString[l] == "i" || tempString[l] == "o" || tempString[l] == "u") {
                    count ++;
                }else{
                }
            }   
            // console.log(count);
            counting.push(count)        
    }
    let max = 0,Maximist
    // for (let d = 0; d < counting.length; d++) {
    //     console.log(counting[d] , "  this is the value of the counting array");
    // }
    for (let t = 0; t <= counting.length; t++) {
        if (counting[t] != 0) {
            
            if (max < counting[t]) {
                max = counting[t]
                Maximist = t
            }
            else if (max == counting[t]){
                max = counting[t]
                Maximist = t
        }
        else{
            console.log("");
        }
    }
    }
    // console.log(Maximist);
    // console.log(max);
    // maxPoint.push(Maximist)
    for (let t = 0; t <= counting.length; t++) {
        if (counting[0] != 0) {
            if (max == counting[t]) {
                maxPoint.push(t)
            }
        }
    }
    for (let e = 0; e < maxPoint.length; e++) {
        console.log("{", elementsArray[maxPoint[e]] ,"}")        
    }
}
findSubstring("captainamerica", 3);
```

The bigger your size of the substring will be the less chances that there will be less substring with same number of vowels in it

Comment: What would be the output for `aaagtaayuhiejjhgiiiouaae`?

Comment: @ack it depends how long do you want the substring if you put the length 3 then the output will be 
{ a,a,a }
{ i,i,i }
{ i,i,o }
{ i,o,u }
{ o,u,a }
{ u,a,a }
{ a,a,e }

else if you put the length 5 then the outpuit will be

{ i,i,i,o,u }
{ i,i,o,u,a }
{ i,o,u,a,a }
{ o,u,a,a,e }

Comment: I think your code does not answer the question. The task is to find the longest sequence of `a`s, followed by the longest sequence of `e`s, and so on.

Comment: @ack actually it does but it will give you one extra option (length of the substring) i was given this question in a job code test so that's why i shared it i you want the same answer according to the question then change code a bit from the end of the function